# Change css style and append text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get id of clicked button and with that case I want to change change/add class of specifiv div.

Here is the code:

```
$("input").click(function (e) {
    var idClicked = e.target.id;
    switch (idClicked) {
        case 'regiesterButton':
            $('regiesterAlert').css('class', 'alert alert-danger');
            $('regiesterAlert').append('<b>Error</b> Blabla')
            break;
        case 'loginButton':
            break;
        case 'loginButton':
            break;
    }
});
```

EDIT:
After it steps into case there is exception:

```
if(!jQuery)throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery");+function(a).....
```

What`s wrong in the code?

Comment: regiesterAlert is class or id?  use .regiesterAlert if class  and #regiesterAlert if id

Comment: When the problem is with jQuery interacting with DOM, you should also include the corresponding HTML in the question.

Comment: **Don't** add new question as _EDIT: I'm having this problem too_, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For classes you should use `.` and for id `#`

```
$('.regiesterAlert').css('class', 'alert alert-danger');
   ^
   |
$('.regiesterAlert').append('<b>Error</b> Blabla')
   ^
   |
```

also instead of `.css('class')` you should use `.addClass`, and instead of using same selector twice  you can use it once

```
$('.regiesterAlert')
  .addClass('alert alert-danger')
  .append('<b>Error</b> Blabla')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.regiesterAlert').addClass('alert alert-danger');
$('.regiesterAlert').append('<b>Error</b> Blabla')
```

Comment: Add the explanation with code. Only code-dumps with `Try this` are not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('.regiesterAlert').addClass('alert alert-danger');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although this will solve the problem, please add some explanation of what OP is doing wrong and how to solve that problem.